# password_verify if {invalid} else{

Tags: php, mysql, security

I want to replace sha1 with password_hash, and I need to make the password_verify run like: **if invalid = do set of functions, else login**.
However in password_verify manual I only find this:

```
<?php
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // valid
}
else {
    // invalid
}
```

How do I get something like this:

```
<?php
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // invalid = run set of functions
}
else {
    // login
}
```

I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: ok and the PHP version is what? Plus, what is the password column's length? If it's less than 60, it's a problem.

Comment: Keep R'ing TMs http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: So you want the `if` to be if `password_verify()` returns `invalid`? Like `if (!password_verify($password, $hash))`?

Comment: @Sean Yeah, exactly!

Comment: As the last two have said - just negate your logic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php): NOT (!)

```
if (!password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // invalid = run set of functions
}
else {
    // login
}
```

Really basic stuff.

Comment: That's what happens when you skip the basic school :)) TX man!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<?php
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // invalid = run set of functions
}
else {
    // login
}
```

to

```
<?php
if (!password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // invalid = run set of functions
}
else {
    // login
}
```

The ! operator means NOT. So it'll read if not true then invalid, else valid